# IntelliLock 1.5 An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Tags: .net, prism, intellilock

After ofbuscation in IntelliLock 1.5 one of my dll's prism module stop loading (unity), the error message is: “An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)”

First i had a reference to portable library (.net, Silverlight 4) that hold some shared objects. And the error was something like "Cant load referenced library System.Windows" although  there was no UI in portable library and was no reference to System.Windows dll. But after half of a day of tuning IntelliLock and trying to figure out  where the problem is, unity begin to fall with "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)" error.

First i thought the problem in referencing portable dll. I replace this library with normal .net one, but error is still the same.

I'm using .Net 4 Client Profile. WPF, C#, Prism 4, unity.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This might be the target platform, try compiling them all explicitly x86 or x64.

Comment: Yes i know this, all assemblies is x86. And no problems before obfuscate this particular dll.

Comment: I think you need to go to Intellilock for support - it sounds like a bug in their obfuscator. Unless someone has seen this specific problem before I doubt we'd be able to help you.

Comment: I already send this issue to support, but usually they didn't answer questions. :) Only hope that someone had the same problem.

Comment: If you're a customer and they don't answer your questions then that's pretty shoddy support. You might not be their highest priority but they should still acknowledge your email and give you a time-frame for getting back to you. I'd chase them for a response, maybe even phone them to check they're looking into it for you.

Comment: Yep, I am their customer for about 3 years and 2 versions of IntelliLock, but never get even an answer for support. May be that guys dont like write letters or my english so bad, I don know :).

Comment: I have a little progress with my issue. After i replace some warnings (throw exception form property) in my assembly it starts to load after obfuscation. But if i use portable assembly the same error is appears.

Comment: All assemblies that reference  to portable dll have this warning "Warning 35 CA0060 : The indirectly-referenced Silverlight assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. Silverlight reference assemblies should be specified with the '/reference' switch."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run into similar (??) problem some time ago so I suggest:

1) Check if all dependencies satisfied. Run DependencyWalker and check that there's no red lines - nothing missing (please read some documentation because sometimes it mark for example IEShims.dll as missing **but you don't need it**) -- Use **correct** version of DependecyWalker (x86/x64) on **correct** comp

2) As Denis Kucherov already sad: Check **how** parent and/or child (dependant) object was compiled. Once we tryed to use .NET project compiled by default as 'Any CPU' on x64 bit machine to load by reference C++ DLL compiled for x86 - no go -> exceptions, exceptions, crash...

3) *Hardcore level* - Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals and check for any missing/not found errors (if any). It's a loooong list sometimes...

My guess that DLL you trying to load actually loading ok but it itself depend on some other DLL that not present

P.S. You mention .Net Client Profile - just try it once with full .NET Framework and check if it helps - if so - double check that .NET Client profile installed in target comp

Comment: the main point here that all works fine but one .dll module after IntelliLock obfuscation.

Comment: even more, dll not working only if it was obfuscated with portable dll reference.

Comment: check with Dependency Walker 2.2 thrown a red light on ieshims.dll is that really crucial in my situation?

Comment: So - let me understand - problem happens **only** after obfuscation and it **does** normally work in regular/normal compilation ? You obfuscate all files together and run (for example) NCover and check that namespaces not mangled ? It seems that the problem in obfuscation process and not in .NET compilation... Could it be ?

Comment: Yes it happens only after obfuscation and if i referenced portable dll. I dont have NCover, should i check it?

Comment: I think problem is with IntelliLock

Comment: Right now i think in the direction how to exclude problem types from obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

as Rup suggested, this was entirely a InTelliLock bug. I managed to overcome it just with disabling lock settings for some libraries. The good new is that problem was in locking logic not in obfuscation. It took a few days to fix problem.

I still dont have any answer from support team, and as said before i'm actually did not expect it.